# Decomposition of V using generalized eigenspaces, one-dimensional case.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble figuring out how to show the base case of this fact.

Suppose $T$ is an element of $L(V)$.
Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.
Suppose $\beta=(v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}, v_n)$ is a basis of $V$ such that $[T]_{\beta}$ is upper triangular.
Then lambda appears on the diagonal of $[T]_{\beta}$ precisely $\dim(G(\lambda, T))$ times.

Pf: Write $n=\dim(V)$

[by induction on $n$] Let $n=1$

*This is what I need help with*: most proofs I have found say that this is obvious.  However, I need to argue it precisely.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

If $n=\dim V=1$, then there is $\mu\in\Bbb K$ such that $T=\mu\cdot id_V$. Assume as a contradiction that $\mu\ne\lambda$. Then $$G(\lambda,T)=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}\ker ((\lambda-\mu)\cdot id_V)^k=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}\ker ((\lambda-\mu)^k\cdot id_V)=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}\{0\}=\{0\}$$

Since by definition this is not the case, $\lambda=\mu$. And of course, in any basis the matrix associated to $T$ is the $1\times 1$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\mu\end{pmatrix}$.

Moreover, since $\dim V=1$ and $G(\lambda,T)$ is a non-zero subspace, $\dim G(\lambda,T)=1$.

Comment: Three questions:  When you use the set notation K, what do you mean? Does it mean complex numbers? Second, what does idv mean? Does it mean identity operator of V? Last, in your proof, is n an element of natural numbers?

Comment: $\Bbb K$ is an arbitrary field (as in "$V$ is a vector space over the field $\Bbb K$"). Yes, $id_V$ is the identity map $V\to V$. The $n$-s in the unions ought to have been (as they are now) "$k$" instead.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask for a few more clarifications?  I know I am being a bit exhaustive, but I need to be able to explain it thoroughly and precisely.1.)  When you write "T=μ⋅idV"-How do I know this? 2.)When you write "Since, by definition, this is not the case"-Can you be specific why this is not the case(by definition)? 3.) You write "...and G(lambda, T) is a nonzero subspace"-Why do I know that it is a non-zero subspace? 4.) Can you explain to me why lambda appears on the diagonal of [T]β (where  [T]β=[lambda])